# PHP class with 3 objects iterate through array

Tags: php, arrays, class

I have to demonstrate PHP class with 3 objects of that class, then add these class objects to an array, and iterate through the array displaying the object data variable values in an HTML table.
I was not able to even echo values without a table, not sure what is wrong there.
Here is what I got so far.

```
    <?php

$output ='';
class car {
  
  public $make;
  public $model;
  public $year;

  
  function set_make($make) {
    $this->make = $make;
  }
    
    function set_model($model) {
    $this->model = $model;
  }
    
    
    function set_year($year) {
    $this->year = $year;
  }
    
  function get_make() {
    return $this->make;
  }
    
    
  function get_modele() {
    return $this->model;
  }
    
  function get_year() {
    return $this->year;
  }
}

$car1 = new Car();
$car1->set_make('Toyota');
$car1->set_model('Rav4');
$car1->set_year('2018');


$car2 = new Car();
$car2->set_make('Acura');
$car2->set_model('ILX');
$car2->set_year('2012');

$carArray = array(); 

array_push( $carArray, $car1, $car2);



$output .= '<TABLE border="2" align="left">';

$output .= "<TR>";
$output .= '<TH align="left">' . "Make" . "</TH>";
$output .= '<TH>' . "Model" . "</TH>";
$output .= '<TH>' . "Year" . "</TH>";
$output .= "</TR>";

return $output;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$output ='';
class car {
  
  public $make;
  public $model;
  public $year;

  
  function set_make($make) {
    $this->make = $make;
  }
    
    function set_model($model) {
    $this->model = $model;
  }
    
    
    function set_year($year) {
    $this->year = $year;
  }
    
  function get_make() {
    return $this->make;
  }
    
    
  function get_modele() {
    return $this->model;
  }
    
  function get_year() {
    return $this->year;
  }
}

$car1 = new Car();
$car1->set_make('Toyota');
$car1->set_model('Rav4');
$car1->set_year('2018');


$car2 = new Car();
$car2->set_make('Acura');
$car2->set_model('ILX');
$car2->set_year('2012');

$carArray = array(); 

array_push( $carArray, $car1, $car2);
$final_array = json_decode(json_encode($carArray), true);

$output = '<table>';
$output .= '<tr><th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Year</th></tr>';
foreach ($final_array as $key => $car_data) {
    
    
    $output .= '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', $car_data).'</td></tr>';
    
}

$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!